# Problems with Amplify and Vite

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, aws-amplify, vite

I am getting errors while setting up Amplify Authentication with `React` and `Vite`.

This is what I have tried already.

**Packages used:**

```
"@aws-amplify/ui-react": 4.2.0
"aws-amplify": 5.0.5
```

**Main.jsx**

```
import Amplify from "aws-amplify"
import awsExports from "./aws-exports"
Amplify.configure(awsExports)
```

**vite.config.js**

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import postcss from './postcss.config.js'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  define: {
    'process.env': process.env,
    'global': {}
  },
  css: {
    postcss,
  },
  plugins: [react()],
  resolve: {
    alias: [
      {
        find: /^~.+/,
        replacement: (val) => {
          return val.replace(/^~/, "");
        },
      },
      {
        find: './runtimeConfig', replacement: './runtimeConfig.browser',
      }
    ],
  },
  build: {
    commonjsOptions: {
      transformMixedEsModules: true,
    }
  } 
})
```

Running, `npm run dev`, app crashes and console has this error:

```
'Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module '/node_modules/.vite/aws-amplify.js?v=d4f24853' does not provide an export named 'default' (at main.jsx:5:1)'
```

Comment: From the docs: https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/auth/getting-started/q/platform/js/#option-1-use-pre-built-ui-components.

`import { Amplify } from 'aws-amplify';`

Comment: Did you find a solution to this one?